# How is this electric guitar tuned?

Tags: guitar, alternative-tunings

The song in question is "Pet Carrot" by Palehound.

You can hear the guitar right at the beginning of this video:

I thought it was a bass at first. Anyone know the tuning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guitar is not just tuned in a standard tuning which is transposed down. From what I can hear and see, the low three strings are definitely

`C G D`

I believe that the high strings are just standard tuning, which would make the complete tuning

`C G D G B E`

which is not one of the standard open tunings but a mix of drop C and standard tuning.

The tuning of the low three stings is obvious from the intro riff:

```
-------2-------------2-----
----0-----0------3-------3-
-0-----------0-------------
```

Comment: Great ear! Thanks! This tuning is the first variation of [Drop C Tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_C_tuning#Variations). Apparently, Bob Dylan once favored this tuning.

Comment: @Kyle: I've learned something too; didn't know that this was a standard variation of drop C.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a baritone to me. They use a slightly longer scale length, and thicker strings, and one of the many tunings is C F Bb Eb G C, so standard chord shapes can be used. Not as low as a standard bass guitar - in fact the bottom 4 strings (in B E A D tuning) are an octave above normal 5 string bass guitar tuning.

Comment: I think you're close, but I am not sure it is B E A D F# B tuning. The root note of the main progression (the very first note that is played) is a C2, correct? If you look closely at the guitarist's hands, at 1:15 in the video, you can see that this root note is the open first string.

Comment: @Kyle - you're right, answer edited appropriately. There is no one standard tuning for baritone. Players often use two or three different tunings - but mostly voiced similarly to the guitar. Root note is open 6th string! 1st being the thinnest.